# Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $A$ is PSD and $B$ NSD. If $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$, show that $AB=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $B$ a negative semidefinite matrix. If $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$, show that $AB=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a definition in which "positive semidefinite" implies symmetric, then we can simply proceed as follows. Because $B$ is negative semidefinite, it has a decomposition $B = -MM^T$. It follows that
$$
0 = \operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(AMM^T) = -\operatorname{tr}(M^TAM).
$$
$M^TAM$ is negative semidefinite. So, $\operatorname{tr}(M^TAM) = 0 \implies M^TBM = 0$. It follows that all vectors $x$ in the column space of $M$, which is also the column space of $B$, satisfy $Ax = 0$. Thus, we have $AB = 0$, which was what we wanted.

---

Note that if we use the more general definition where we only require $x^TAx \geq 0$ for $x \neq 0$, the statement fails. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&-1}.
$$